Shouldn't the solution for $\int \frac{x^2 - x}{x} dx$ include $x \neq 0$ as a restriction?

Working on: Rhonda Huettenmueller. (2024). Business Calculus Demystified (p. 335)

I have to solve the following integral:
$\int \frac{x^2 - x}{x}dx$
The solution given is:

$
\frac{x^2 - x}{x} \text{ simplifies to}
$
$
\frac{x^2}{x} - \frac{x}{x} = x - 1
$


$\text{This is simpler to integrate.}$
$\int \frac{x^2 - x}{x} \, dx = \int (x - 1) dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x + C$

My question is: shouldn't the final answer include a restriction stating that $x - 1$ is defined for $x \neq 0$ ?

If you are integrating a function over an interval it is useful to define the function at every point of the interval. If your interval includes $x=0$ and you declare a value for the function at $x=0$ pretty much any basic definition of the integral will give the same answer, because the rogue point can be confined to an interval as small as you like. What is the function you are integrating? (You can choose a value to make it continuous, in which case general results apply, but the basic definition of the integral can be applied whatever real (finite) value is chosen)

Evaluating the integral
$$\int f(x)\,dx$$
is the same as finding a function $F(x)$ (with the same domain as $f(x)$) whose derivative is $f(x)$. So it is already implied that $0$ is not in the domain of your solution. However, it is not wrong to reinforce this information in your answer.

just consider the limit of the integrand as x goes to zero, it exist and well defined so there's no problem here and there's no need for the restriction.
disclaimer: physicist here so I might be missing something in terms of rigor and so on.

You have that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(x-1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}(x-1)=-1$$
So you can extend $f$ as follows:
$\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x), & x\ne 0 \\ -1, & x=0 \end{cases}$
Now, $\tilde{f}$ is continuous and admit antiderivative as you computed.
